# User Control Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have followed [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN.

The template works fine but i got 2 big problems.

I can't access the controls in the template even if i decorate the template with these

```
[TemplateContainer(typeof(MessageContainer))]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
```

Second, I get a design time error which is really bad:

```
Error Creating Control - TemplateTest1
Type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'MessageTemplate'.
```

Now, why I want this is because user controls are great and easy, so i want to create user control that will produce this

```
 <div class="FormFiled">
--- here i want the ability to put controls that i want ----
<div class="Wrapper">
</div>
</div>
```

So if templating does not work, is there way to achieve this other than templating ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code of the template located?
Is it in the App_Code folder does it belong to some namespace your page does not have a glue about ?

For example I use the following template

```
namespace GUI.Controls
{

public class GvTemplate : ITemplate
```

...

and in the code behind I have to call it as follows :

```
colField.ItemTemplate = new GUI.Controls.GvTemplate()
```

If you are not creating the template dynamically you would have to register the control at the top of the page ...

Comment: thanks for reply man, 
i am using website project, and no the control is not in APP_Code it is in a normal  folder called ControlTemplate along with the test ASPX page.
and i have followed exactly what the article suggested, no dynamic template, a replica of the article.